# Evernote Api : How can i get a list of my account notes that is linked with the developer account

Tags: php, api, evernote

I've tested all of the php examples that came with the API and none gives me results.
The Api was installed with composer.
i have some errors resulted when running the script ( ips,locations,keys were changed here )

```
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324822 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught EDAM\\Error\\EDAMUserException in /server/public_html/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/UserStore/UserStore.php:2603
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324885 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324899 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /server/public_html/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/UserStore/UserStore.php(543): EDAM\\UserStore\\UserStore_getUser_result->read(Object(Thrift\\Protocol\\TBinaryProtocol))
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324913 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /server/public_html/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/UserStore/UserStore.php(504): EDAM\\UserStore\\UserStoreClient->recv_getUser()
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324925 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 [internal function]: EDAM\\UserStore\\UserStoreClient->getUser('oceanindien-ful...')
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324936 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /server/public_html/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/Evernote/Store/Store.php(50): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324973 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr: #4 /server/public_html/test.php(207): Evernote\\Store\\Store->__call('getUser', Array)
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324984 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr: #5 {main}
[Sat Apr 20 02:20:51.324993 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25930] [client *ip*] mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /server/public_html/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/UserStore/UserStore.php on line 2603
```

```
$token = 'my-real-token-here';
$sandbox = true;
$china   = false;

$client = new \Evernote\Client($token, $sandbox, null, null, $china);
$search = new \Evernote\Model\Search('comores');

$notebook = null;

$scope = \Evernote\Client::SEARCH_SCOPE_BUSINESS;

$order = \Evernote\Client::SORT_ORDER_REVERSE | \Evernote\Client::SORT_ORDER_RECENTLY_CREATED;

$maxResult = 5;
$results = $client->findNotesWithSearch($search, $notebook, $scope, $order, $maxResult);
var_dump($results);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $noteGuid    = $result->guid;
    $noteType    = $result->type;
    $noteTitle   = $result->title;
    $noteCreated = $result->created;
    $noteUpdated = $result->updated;
}
```

I've checked the linked account that has notes with those tags or keys but the api gives me no results returned.

How can i get the list of my TAGS from the linked account ?
How can i get a list of my notes and/or notebooks from my account ?

The sandbox key is full access not basic.

I've searched for examples that i tried on the server, but the return was or ERROR 500 or empty page,

I've echo/printed the results but no results returned !

What i do wrong, or what do i need to do so the api work ?

Comment: RTM for the exception/error (tl;dr invalid token): https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Errors.html#Struct_EDAMUserException, also mentioned in https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/error_handling.php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you so much.
stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to protected method Evernote\\Client::getNoteStore() from context '' in /server/public_html/test.php:295
Do you know how to fix this ?